# Return the indices of max value of multi-dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Given that there is a 5D numpy array x: [a][b][c][d][e]

if I provide the first two indices [a][b], how can I return the indices of the last 3 incides [c][d][e], that gives the location of max value?

i.e., i fixed the first two indices [2][4][c][d][e], how can I return the indices (c,d,e) that gives the max value if first two incides are (2,4)?

Comment: Have you looks at `np.argmax`?

Comment: One approach is simply be `x[a,b,:,:,:].argmax()`